# html scan image from scanner on a web page and save the image to local folder or back to page

Tags: html

Printer type **hp officejet pro 6830**
Is there a way to scan from html/java script image from a scanner ?

If it cant be done can anyone recommend a **lib** for java that give access to the printer/scanner.

The over all idea is to add a **button** to web page and scan image back to the page or to a local folder

I already tried using **Scanner.js**: HTML/JavaScript Web Twain WIA

but it didnt work for me not sure why?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can kinda be done.

Before starting I must specify that I'm trying this on my HP PhotoSmart network printer, but it should apply to yours as well.

If from your browser you surf to your printer IP address (I suppose you're using it as a network printer, ie. *http://192.168.1.79*), you should find a couple of options and the ability to scan documents from the web browser itself (you might have to enable this function first from the settings).

It works and you could spend hours reverse-engineering that things. Luckly, it seems someone has already done that: [hp-webscan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hp-webscan) and it's only ~60 lines so it's easy to convert to another environment/language.

Otherwise HP printers should expose a CUPS (IPP) / SANE interface and you could use that.

[*SANE*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanner_Access_Now_Easy) (*Scanner Access Now Easy*) is a set of API to communicate with scanners across a network. I gave you the link to the Wikipedia page describing the technology. Here's an example of binding for Node: [node-sane](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sane).

Comment: i tryd to get this to work for few hours and this not working i just need the address to the page on the printer web server and what parameters needed for scan ;/

Comment: I don't have your exact model so I cannot provide you the links directly. I've found a thread in the HP support forum referring to your exact model showing how to enable webscan (there's even a video, see the last post [here](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Scanning-Faxing-and-Copying/HP-Officejet-Pro-6830-scan-via-web-control-panel/td-p/5386429)). Basically, in order to get correct links, you should perform a scan from the browser an check the network inspector in your browser for requests to the printer. Hope it helps. If you're getting SSL errors, just continue and arrange the code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Python Flask service, which can be called from javascript to start scanner, and get the scanned image as pdf. This python code will allow you to use image scanner from a web page. An example for a web page "client_page.html".
You can edit the code so it will return an image :
https://github.com/KHBillel/ImageScanner4Web

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30251965)